# smooth curve of genus $0$ and Brauer group

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, arithmetic-geometry, brauer-group

In [this blog](https://ayoucis.wordpress.com/2016/04/29/around-abelian-schemes-over-the-integers/) of Alex Youcis, I see a sentence in the proof of theorem 4 which says that "since $C$ has genus 0 that it defines a class $[C]\in\mathrm{Br}(\mathbb{Q})$ which is trivial if and only if $C\cong\mathbb{P}^1_\mathbb{Q}$". And the definition of the [Brauer group](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/074J) of a field is the equivance classes of central simple algebras.

So the question is that what the map and the inverse map are between $\mathrm{Br}(\mathbb{Q})$ and the set of all smooth curves of genus $0$ over $\mathbb{Q}$(I don't know if this is a set).

My thoughts: Smooth curves of genus $0$ corresponds to a quadratic form over $\mathbb{Q}$(By Riemann-Roch and embed this curve into $\mathbb{P}^2$ as a quadratic curve), and a quadratic form corresponds to an element in the Brauer group. Is this right?

Thanks!

Comment: 1) Alex Youcis frequents the site (at least he used to) so there are hopes for an explanation (that I would welcome). 2) Richard Brauer is my academic grandfather, and is worthy, but I have not seen him being honored by writing his name in lower case, yet :-)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Sorry, I just edited my question and I  have modified my mistakes!

Comment: @Sssss Your thought is roughly correct. What is true more generally is that twists of  $\mathbb{P}^{n-1}_k$ correspond to classes in the Galois cohomology group $H^1(G_k,\mathrm{PGL}_n(\overline{k})$. One knows that the colimit over $n$ of such objects is just $\mathrm{Br}(k)$. So, $\mathrm{Br}(k)$ classifies twists of $\mathbb{P}^{n-1}_k$ (as $n$ varies). The relevant phrase is 'Brauer-Severi variety'. You can look in Bjorn Poonen's book *Rational points on varieties* or Gille and Szamuely's book *Central simple algebras and Galois cohomology* for more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just to get this off the unanswered list I will turn my comment in to an answer.

In general for a field $k$ there is a bijection between (isomorphism classes of) central simple algebras over $k$ of dimension $n^2$ and twists of $\mathbb{P}^{n-1}_k$. One can find the details of this in Bjorn Poonen's book *Rational points on varieties* or Gille and Szamuely's book *Central simple algebras and Galois cohomology*. The operative phrases here are 'Brauer group', 'central simple algebras', and 'Brauer-Severi varieties'.

As you guessed, under this correspondence the conic $V(ax^2+by^2-z^2)\subseteq\mathbb{P}^2_k$, which is a twist of $\mathbb{P}^1_k$, corresponds to the quaternion algebra $\left(\frac{a,b}{k}\right)$.

Comment: I have been waiting for you today! And I am very glad that you took time to explain these questions! Thanks!